# "Or" and "And" operators in Octopus variable substitution syntax

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is there some way to use logical "or" and "and" operators in variable substitution syntax like the following?

```
#{if Octopus.Action[Smoke Test] && Octopus.Action[Smoke Test].Output.FailedSmokeTestMessage}
    <h3 style="color: red">Failed Smoke Tests</h3>
    #{Octopus.Action[Smoke Test].Output.FailedSmokeTestMessage}
#{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. See the [documentation on variable substitution syntax](https://octopus.com/docs/reference/variable-substitution-syntax). Instead you could try nesting your if blocks.

```
#{if Octopus.Action[Smoke Test]}
  #{Octopus.Action[Smoke Test].Output.FailedSmokeTestMessage}
    <h3 style="color: red">Failed Smoke Tests</h3>
    #{Octopus.Action[Smoke Test].Output.FailedSmokeTestMessage}
  #{/if}
#{/if}
```

There is no [test case for this in Octostache](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octostache/blob/master/source/Octostache.Tests/UsageFixture.cs), the open-source templating engine, so there's no guarantee it works. It is pretty easy to set up a test project for Octostache using its Nuget package to test it out and play around with syntax.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what i had in place before for "and" - it works. But in case of replicating "or" you just have to duplicate "if"s :(

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: Is the answer missing the `if` from the second line?